# Syntax error in kmeans python code at KMeans.fit(:,x1)?

Tags: python, syntax, k-means

I am new to python and I came across a tutorial for kMeans clustering. I've tried to write and re-write and I'm at a loss. (The "<" is not part of the code. It's the only way I could get indention.)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


x1 = dataset.loc[:, ["PASTDUE","AGE"]].values
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
wcss = []
for k in range (1,11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, init="k-means++")
    KMeans.fit(:, x1)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.grid()
plt.plot(range(1,11),wcss, linewidth=2, color="red", marker="8")
plt.xlabel("K Value")
plt.ylabel("WCSS")
```

I get the following error message
[SyntaxError:invalid syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPSQA.png) pointing at this line:

```
KMeans.fit(:, x1)
```

Comment: use instance `kmeans` instead of `KMeans`

Comment: Thanks Mehmaam, I tried replacing KMeans with kmeans in "KMeans.fit" and I get the same error.

Comment: try this `kmeans.fit(x1)` instead of  `KMeans.fit(:, x1)`

Comment: Thank you Mehmaam, I don't get that error anymore. but I get another error message. I'll search through the questions. Thank a mil.